# Functional operator for (un)packing operators * and **?

Tags: python, operators, pep

Python has the 2 operators `*` and `**` for packing and unpacking of parameters, e.g.

```
print(*[1,2,3,4])
```

or

```
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

There is no mention of these operators in [the operator module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), and there is no way to overwrite them. 
For example, this could be a thing:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5
        self.b = 10

    def __starstar__(self):
        # Not to be confused with __pow__!
        # Should return something that can be unpacked by the default ** operator
       return {"a": self.a, "b": self.b}

def print_a_b(a, b):
    print(f"a is {a} and b is {b}")

print_a_b(**Test())
# Should be unpacked into a and b parameters
# and print "a is 5 and b is 10"
```

It kind of works with the `*` operator and iterables:

```
class Test2(object):

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from range(10)

print(*Test2())
# prints "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

I understand that we can not use `**` and `__getitem__`, since we don't know the items that may be present. But why is there no operator that can be overwritten for `**`, and **why is there no operator in the `operator` module for `*` and `**`**?

One reason I could think of is that this would contribute to coupling in the wrong direction between classes, i.e. `Test` now implicitly knows about the signature of `print_a_b`.

A better use case might be a `Config` class that does some additional setup and can then be passed to another function, e.g `run(**Config())`.

Comment: What *would* be in the operator module? That syntax isn't an operator, and `tuple` and `dict` already exist.

Comment: Couldn't it be considered a binary operator? I understand that this is not how it is currently built, but why not?

Comment: Definitely not *binary*, given only one "operand"... But you seem to be confusing several things (the operator module, the data model, magic methods) so the question is still unclear. You *can* implement both `*` and `**` unpacking, per the duplicates.

Comment: how else would you call it if not binary? There is exactly one operand, which is the object itself. For the operator module, I was thinking of something like `d = dict(map(operator.starstar, list_of_dicts))`

Comment: Sorry I mean unary of course, not binary